# Cloud Dataflow to trigger email upon failure

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

When running Dataflow job in Google cloud, how can the Dataflow pipeline be configured to shoot an email upon failure (or successful completion)? Is there an easy option, where it can be configured inside the Pipeline program, or any other options?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option from my practice is to use Apache Airflow(on GCP, it's Cloud Composer).

Cloud Composor/Apache Airflow can send you failure emails when DAG (jobs) face failures. So I can host my job in Airflow and it sends emails upon failures.

You can check[1] to see if it satisfies your need

1. https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You could use GCP Logs Explorer https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface and create alerts based on conditions.